# Is it possible to slightly modify my symmetric difference function so that it can accept an unknown number of arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, filter, reduce

I've created this codepen http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/ZWxvzm when trying to find an array containing symmetric difference of two or more arrays.

My function works OK but only if four arguments are passed. How can I modify my function so that it can accept an unknown number of arguments? There is a potentially repeatable block of code that perhaps could be part of a `for` loop or `reduce` / `map` methods. I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

```
symmetricDifference([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6], [2,4,6,7], [8,9])
// should return an array containing [1,4,5,7,8,9]

symmetricDifference([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6])
// should return an array containing [1,2,5,6]

var arrA = [1,2,3,4];
var arrB = [3,4,5,6];
var arrC = [2,4,6,7];
var arrD = [8,9];

function symmetricDifference(arr) {
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  let result = [];

  result = args[0].concat(args[1]).filter(function(item) {
    return args[0].indexOf(item) === -1 || args[1].indexOf(item) === -1;
  });

  result = result.concat(args[2]).filter(function(item) {
    return result.indexOf(item) === -1 || args[2].indexOf(item) === -1;
  });

  result = result.concat(args[3]).filter(function(item) {
    return result.indexOf(item) === -1 || args[3].indexOf(item) === -1;
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, use a simple `for` loop over `args`. Please show us your attempt if you didn't succeed.

Comment: Hint: Start with `var result = args[0];`

Comment: Is it always in groups of four? Group your arguments into groups of four then loop those groups, selecting each of the four elements in the group as you are in your example.

Comment: @Bergi I've implemented your hints and the function works as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hints by @Bergi I've introduced a `for` loop and an initial value `var result = args[0];` The function is working now as desired as it accepts an unknown number of arguments. I've updated the original codepen (http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/ZWxvzm) to demonstrate this implementation.

```
function symmetricDifference(arr) {
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  let result = args[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    result = result.concat(args[i]).filter(function(item) {
      return result.indexOf(item) === -1 || args[i].indexOf(item) === -1;
    });
  }
  // remove duplicates and sort
  return Array.from(new Set(result)).sort((a, b) => a - b);
}
```

Comment: It's easier to let your loop run from `1` to `args.length`. Also there is no reason to introduce that `temp` variable, you can just work only on `result`.

Comment: I've just updated the `loop` conditions and removed the unnecessary `temp` variable as per your hints. The code seems much cleaner now. Much appreciated.